# Node + Express .post route throwing error. Expected callback, got object

Tags: node.js, express

I'm currently working on an app using Express + Node. I recently added a new `.post` route to the `app.js` file, using the following syntax:

```
app.post('/api/posts/saveComment', posts.saveComment);
```

`posts` is defined above as:

```
var posts = require('./routes/posts.js');
```

And `saveComment` is defined as so:

```
exports.saveComment = function(req, res) {
    //function stuff in here, yada yada
}
```

Now, node is throwing an error when I try to run the app:

```
Error: .post() requires a callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
```

`saveComment` is clearly a function, I'm not understanding why it can't see this. I have another function defined right above `saveComment` that I'm able to reference completely fine without error, however copying that functions contents to that of `saveComment` still yields the same error. I'm at a loss, any help is much appreciated.

Per request, contents of `posts.js`

```
var mongo = require('../mongo.js');

exports.queryAll = function(req, res) {
    var db = mongo.db;

    db.collection('posts', function(err, collection) {
        collection.find().toArray(function(err, doc) {
            if (err)
                res.send({error:err})
            else
                res.send(doc)

            res.end();
        });
    });
}

exports.saveCommment = function(req, res) {
    var db      = mongo.db,
        BSON    = mongo.BSON,
        name    = req.body.name,
        comment = req.body.comment,
        id      = req.body.id;

    db.collection('posts', function(err, collection) {
        collection.update({_id:new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, { $push: { comments: { poster:name, comment:comment }}}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("ERROR: " + err);
                res.send(err);
            }
            res.send({success:"success"});
            res.end();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you please show exports of module posts?

Comment: @syned -- posted the contents

Comment: This is really embarassing...`saveComment` has 3 m's in the `posts.js`. Im going to go take a nap.

Comment: Try to use module.exports..., Sorry for delay

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well...embarrassing answer, `saveCommment` is defined with 3 m's in my `posts.js`. Ugh.

Comment: The orginal error message already hints, it's typo.. `toString.call(undefined)` === `[object Undefined]` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at other related questions?

Such as:

[Understanding callbacks in Javascript and node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552244/understanding-callbacks-in-javascript-and-node-js?rq=1)

[understanding the concept of javascript callbacks with node.js, especially in loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506240/understanding-the-concept-of-javascript-callbacks-with-node-js-especially-in-lo)

I've battled with this topic myself and have to say that callbacks are fundamental for a happy node.js app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm aware of callbacks in JS, quite fondly. Thanks for suggestion tho :D

Answer (score 0):

I write my exports the following way. maybe this will help you :)

```
  module.export = {
     savecomment : function(){
         yada yada
      },
     nextfunction : function(){
     }
   }
```

Using the functions:

```
 var helper = require('helper.js')

 helper.savecomment();
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot in a minute, will report back