# jQuery access to node.js global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

There are 3 components to my problem.

1. Declaring a server side (node.js) variable to hold data for the duration of the server run - just a number.
2. Sending a number to the server from the client (jQuery) to update the server value.
3. Sending a number back to the client as calculated by the server from the new number.

I haven't been successful creating a variable I can access - I have tried a separate .js file with `export.global`, as well as `var sum = require('./sum');`

My best guess to send the data to the server is `$.post ('/sum', 'entry=20', showNewTotal);`.

I can also get it on to the HTML display in showNewTotal `$('#currentSum').text('data');`

This seems like it should be simple, however I haven't been able to identify any examples.

Comment: Uhm, do you have a route for `app.post('/sum')` ?

Comment: yes - `app.get('/sum', routes);`

Comment: That would be a `get` route for a `post` call. If you're using `$.post` it should be `app.post('/sum', routes)` and of course the routes function has to set the global to whatever is passed in `req.body.entry` etc

Comment: yep, correct on the app.get/app.post.

Answer (score 0):

Your sum module could look like this:

```
module.exports = {sum:0};
```

To set anywhere, you do:

```
var sum = require('./sum');
sum.sum = 10;
```

To retrieve it anywhere else, you do:

```
var sum = require('./sum');    
console.log(sum.sum);
```

So to set it with $.post, you'll need a route set up like adeneo mentioned using app.post('/sum') with a handler that does the set I wrote by grabbing the entry param and then sending back an object like {new_total:sum.sum} that would be used by your showNewTotal function.

Comment: Solved it in combination with [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18540965/node-express-post-route-throwing-error-expected-callback-got-object), got object" post - Thanks!