# sails.js - how to list records from collections?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am using mongodb and I have installed sails-mongodb. I can access mongodb from controller(sails.js).

**Issue 1:** I have created a model using sails command, but I dont know how to create function for insert, edit, list and delete. 
How to load the model into controller?
How to call the model functions from controller?

**Issue 2:** 
In this following controller, I store the values I intend to user in my view in 'data'. I dont know how to create db functions in model section so I have fetched some data from database using find function, but how do I assign that category values into data.list ?

```
 module.exports = {
 index: function (req, res) {

var data = new Object();
data.title            = "Page title";   
data.meta_keywords    = "k1,k2,k3";     
data.meta_description = "sample data";
    data.lists = "";

Category.find().done(function(err, category) {
    data.lists = category;
});

bredcrumbs = new Array();
bredcrumbs[0] = {'text':'Home','link':'Link','active':false};
res.view("pages/home",data);    

},  
   _config: {}  
};
```

I have created one model file with named `category.js`

```
  tableName: 'category',

  module.exports = {

    attributes: {
      name: {
          type:     'STRING',
          required: true
      },
      keyword: {
          type:     'STRING',
          required: true
      },
      image:        'STRING',
      sort_order: 'INTEGER',
      date_added: 'DATETIME',
      status:   'BOOLEAN'
     },

      toJSON: function() {
        var obj = this.toObject();
        return obj;
      }
};
```

Comment: Any issue with the provided answer?

Comment: @marionebl  thanks for the detailed answer. i didnt try but it seems good. i did solved the issue 1 the way you told issue 2 i have used async module....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### To issue 1

All valid model definitions found in the path specified via `sails.config.paths.models` (defaults to `app/models`) should be available both in the `global` scope and in `sails.models` as soon as the `orm hook` is initialized. Read: You do not have to load your models into your controllers manually.

As for custom methods on sails models you have to grasp the concept of instance / model vs. class / collection methods:

**Class / Collection methods**

```
// models/example.js
{
   attributes: {},
   doSomething: function() {
      // scope is not on a model here, there is none initialized
      // e.g. this.toObject() won't work
   }
}
```

Allows you to:

```
Example.doSomething();
```

**Model / Instance methods**

```
// models/example.js
{
   attributes: {
     doSomething: function() {
       // scope is on a model here
       // e.g. this.toObject() will work
     }
   },
}
```

Allows you to:

```
Example.findOne(1).exec(function(err, example) {
  example.doSomething();
});
```

Documentation about collections can be found here: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
Check the sections about instance and class methods.

Applying this to your example means that you'd have to move the `toJSON` method into the `attributes` object to be called at all. But as you are doing nothing with the data in it you just could leave it out as well.

### To issue 2

The reason for the queried `Category` records not reaching the view in your example is that you call `res.view` outside the query's `callback`. This should work:

```
Category.find().done(function(err, categories) {
  data.lists = categories;
  res.view("pages/home",data);  
});
```

I guess it would make sense for you to read up on callbacks in nodejs. Starting point here on SO:
[Understanding callbacks in Javascript and node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552244/understanding-callbacks-in-javascript-and-node-js)